# How much load can these plastic cabinet things hold?

Tags: cabinets

I just moved into my first house and I'm wondering how much load these plastic things (shown in picture) can hold. Each cabinet shelf is held up by four of these things.

Watching diy videos online, I'm convinced that the cabinets themselves can withstand a decent amount of hold. Wondering if these plastic things can, too.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can get metal peg replacements cheap on amazon if the plastic isn't enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If they are like mine I would say over 100 lbs the pin is very strong, I have found the particle board to crumble or shelf break before the pin gave way , the ones that hold in place with the clips are great as they cannot fall out. There should be 4 pins  2 in each side.

Is that shelf in backwards? Mine the front of the shelf has a piece of laminate over the particle board.

Comment: thanks! I added a close up of the pin itself. Upon close up inspection, do you think they're similar to yours?  Re the shelf, it's not backwards. It's sort of laminated on that end, it's just not in the best of shapes.

Comment: Unless there's an extra support in the middle, or these are very narrow shelves, what you need to worry about is the shelf bending in the middle; particle board isn't that sturdy.

Comment: I've got 30"wide shelves  that use those exact clips and are loaded with books and stereo stuff ..... never have had a problem..... +

Comment: I have cabinet in my pantry with the clear clips, I did update the shelf to 3/4 plywood because the shelf loaded with 1 quart glass jars full 2 high is probably close to 100 lbs and the shelves were starting to bow. These clips are great because they are trapped by the shelf they hold better than the metal pins that fall out. As long as the shelf doesn’t bow the shelf holds the pin in place I would bet they would hold more but the shelf even plywood starts to bow. I think my cabinet that has these is the same as jack has about 30” I should remember as I made 4 shelves for it.

Comment: Adding to the comments/answer - the shelves need to fit tight in the cabinet for these pins to give the best results.  If for some reason you had a shelf that was 1/4" too short, the shelf could wobble back and forth and in turn wiggle the pins.  As long as the shelves are original, you should be fine. If you ever need a replacement shelf make sure it fits as good as possible.

Comment: Many thanks guys, I really appreciate all of your help & responses. Shelves are original, I'll make sure to keep an eye out on the shelf starting to bow. If it does, I might rearrange stuff or get better shelves.

Answer (score 0):

I have twice in a few weeks cleaned up glass, syrup and sugar from floor after plastic supports broke. I have invested in metal ones and suggest others do the same if any weight whatsoever on shelves.

Comment: That is rather unusual, Dot. If you have pictures of the remains of the shelf, pins and cabinet side, I'd suggest posting your own question here (with the pics) asking how/why this may have failed. I've usually used metal shelf support pins, but there's not that much to plastic ones that can go wrong - perhaps you got some of inferior quality, had manufacturing defects or perhaps weren't installed correctly. Metal ones are a good idea, though.

Comment: If a shelf is unusually loose in the cabinet, either because it is short or because the sides have bowed outward, there might be enough leverage to break a plastic shelf pin. Or if the pin isn't pushed in all the way. Or if the load is much higher than usual. For bookshelves I prefer the rail-based adjustable shelf support systems, or permanent shelves.